# Lazy or not to use the new keyword without assigning the result?

Tags: c#

I always enjoy learning new approaches and coding methods. My question relates to the use of the "new" keyword.  Would one consider using the new keyword without assignment fair practice?

```
   var example1 = new Item();
   example.Add(testObject);  //OK

   //Using initializer ...
   var example2 = new Item
   {
       Title= "This is the title",
       Summary = "This is the summary"
   }; //Fine again ..


   //but my question relates to using the new keyword like thus ...  

   new Item().Add(testObject);
```

I personally am not keen on the last approach, to me it seems a little lazy and messy haha, but are there any drawbacks or issues associated with using the new 
keyword in this manner? I don't think there are as the garbage collector will clean up but would like a little advice here?

Comment: What's the point of the last line?  The `Item` will die immediately after the `Add` method completes... So.. Whats the point?

Comment: @Dan-o Methods can have side effects

Comment: @LinuxNoob1337: uh huh.  But in the example given it would be odd if there were any side-effects.

Comment: This is my view also, a static method to add test object would seem more appropriate to me. Its just I have seen this quite a lot recently in a few projects, the introduction of managed code introduced this method of coding I think.  I agree, what is the point.

Answer (score 2):

As quick example, when such approach could be used:

```
new DataBaseConnection().executeSingleQueryAndForgetAboutDB(...);
```

so, if it is small utility this oneliner will work

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
new Item().Add(testObject);
```

will create a new instance of object "Item" and run the add method. Without assigning the object reference to a variable you won't be able to do anything else with the Item you created.

So maybe not "bad practice" but of somewhat limited utility.